# Running schedule 40 black steel pipe through concrete foundation wall

Tags: pipe, gas

I need to rerun all the gas line in my house all the way back to the meter, because the current size is 3/4 inch and the meter needs to feed a 1 inch to handle newly added appliances.
The existing pipe runs through the concrete foundation wall 6 inches above ground.

What size hole should I drill through the concrete for a 1" diameter schedule 40 black steel pipe? How do I line/fill/seal the extra space in the hole after running the pipe? Do I need to keep the pipe from resting on the concrete?

Answer (score 1):

Gas lines running underground to a house are supposed to break the surface of the ground before penetrating the  wall and entering the house. This is so that in the event of a gas line leak under ground the leaking gas will follow the pipe to the surface and be expelled to the atmosphere instead of inside the house. Check with your local gas company to see their requirements for running a new line, wall penetration sleeve if required, type of pipe to be used, and are you allowed to run this pipe yourself. Installation codes change with city, township, county, etc. You do not want to replace the line and find out something was not done correctly and it has to be redone. Where I live the codes are strict and you must follow the codes to the letter. So again, call your gas co. and ask first.  Anyway the 1 inch pipe has an ID. of 1.315 inches which should slide into 1-1/4 inch schedule 40 pipe that has an ID of 1.380 inches.

Comment: The existing pipe, enters 6 inches above the ground and the new pipe will do the same. I have no plans to drill holes below the ground line.

Comment: In my area a listed penetration with a mounting flange is required going through the foundation. The flange supports and anchors the pipe. I do agre with d.george's answer. A pressure test should also be done on the new pipe in my area 30 psi is required and the inspector checks the pressure at the start of the inspection then checks at the end 20-30 minutes later if there is any change in pressure no green tag is given.